# Java Calendar class add method adds zero on first call?

Tags: java

When adding 1 year to a Calendar object the first iteration adds zero years, even though it should add 1. Each subsequent call adds 1 year, as it should.  For example:

```
calendarObject.add(Calendar.YEAR,1); //This actually adds nothing    
calendarObject.add(Calendar.YEAR,1); // now it works.
```

**Note:** calendarObject has been set to have a year of 1995 with no other properties set.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? The `for` loop and the initialization of `calendarObject` perhaps.

Comment: I actually just realized my note was the problem. It doesn't seem to like leaving all other variables blank. this problem goes away if I specify a month, day, etc etc. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I have tried `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1995);
 System.out.println("calendar " + cal.getTime());
 cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
 System.out.println("calendar " + cal.getTime());` and it works fine.  Can you give an example to prove your finding?

Comment: @AdrianShum it turns out it the problem was that I was only specifying a year, I wasn't using getInstance. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just works fine.

```
import java.util.Calendar;


public class CalTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1995);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}
```

output:

```
1995
1996
1997
```

Comment: It does work. It turns out my problem was that when you don't use getInstance you can't leave properties like Month, Day, etc blank, which I was. Using getInstance fills all of that out for you.

Answer (score 1):

The **Note** is the source of the problem. You need to have more of the Calendar properties set other than just year. Vikdor's example works because he is using the default Calendar instance returned, which has all class members filled out. Just specifying "1995" will cause odd behavior.